# What language does the vicar speak in the church in Mr Bean S1 E1?

Tags: dialogue, mr-bean

What language is it? Sounds like gibberish with British accent, but a few words seem to be Latin or even French.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Sounds like gibberish

## It is

It's just a indication that the words aren't important to the action....it's just a general *noise* going on in the background.

Having actual words being discernible would tend to concentrate the audience on the dialogue which isn't the point.

> ...the vicar (voiced by Rowan Atkinson off-camera) gives his apparently gibberish sermon
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Bean_(Mr._Bean_episode))</sup>

Plus it means you don't actually have to write them!

Comment: _the vicar (voiced by Rowan Atkinson off-camera)_ - wow, I am really impressed with Rowan Atkinson, such a talent

Comment: You have to think of Mr Bean as a 'silent movie'. The humour is entirely visual, especially in the earlier episodes.

Comment: One of Rowan Atkinson's favorite characters to riff on is incoherent or awkward vicars

Comment: @mai He plays a priest in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umRRCkspaQU